# woocommerce category URL vs wordpress page URL - taxonomy?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, categories, slug

I am using woocommerce 2.4.1 on a self-hosted wordpress 4.3.1 install.

I have WP static pages displaying WC subcategory products.
I would like to have these pages be somehow inline with the WC category tree.

---

**For example:**

I have the following pages:

*example.com/models/*

and

*example.com/models/ginger-j-and-j-licker/*

and here is a typical product url (with "collections" as my shop base)

*example.com/collections/feature-models/ginger-j-j-licker/ginger-j-j-licker-6/*

---

**Going to:**

*example.com/collections/*

brings up a static page that i have created

but going to:

*example.com/collections/feature-models/*

brings up a 404

and going to:

*example.com/collections/feature-models/ginger-j-j-licker/*

redirects to the most recent product in the subcategory

which is all pretty ugly. and people visiting my site have to potentially deal with two separate URL trees- one for my static pages, and the goofy one for woocommerce.

---

**What I would like (for example):**

*example.com/collections/models/*

and

*example.com/collections/models/ginger-j-j-licker/*

to represent both pages AND woocommerce categories.

---

I have tried renaming my pages to match the WC urls and removed the shop base from the WC permalinks.. obviously didn't work.

So my question is,
how do I sync the two together so there is only one URL 'tree' (am i using this word correctly?) that people have to navigate?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved:

installed a simple 301 redirect plugin and redirected all the offending woocommerce urls. seems to be doing the trick.